# Can't brew install gcc(i386-elf-gcc)

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

The main problem I met is that I have installed dependencies such as MPC, MPFR, GMP, use homebrew.  And then I tried to install i386-elf-gcc

Firstly I tapped `brew tap altkatz/homebrew-gcc_cross_compilers` and then `brew install i386-elf-gcc` , for sure some errors occurred.

> configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
>   Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify
>   their locations.  Source code for these libraries can be found at
>   their respective hosting sites as well as at
>   ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/.  See also
>   http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html for additional info.  If
>   you obtained GMP, MPFR and/or MPC from a vendor distribution package,
>   make sure that you have installed both the libraries and the header
>   files.  They may be located in separate packages.

Actually I've already installed MPC and so on with homebrew, these things just located in `/usr/local/Cellar`

Then I `brew install i386-elf-gcc --with-mpc=/usr/local/Cellar/mpc/0.27/bin --with-gmp=/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib --with-mpfr=/usr/local/Cellar/mpfr/3.1.3/lib`

Finally I got this

> configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+. Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify their locations. If you obtained GMP, MPFR and/or MPC from a vendor distribution package, make sure that you have installed both the libraries and the header files. They may be located in separate packages.

Nothing changed...

Could anybody here help me? please.....

just wanna brew install i386-elf-gcc

However thanks everyone viewed this question, thank you

Answer (score 2):

try

```
brew tap nativeos/i386-elf-toolchain
brew install i386-elf-binutils i386-elf-gcc
```

https://github.com/nativeos/homebrew-i386-elf-toolchain

Comment: Now you can use `brew install i386-elf-binutils i386-elf-gcc` directly

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I used  `brew tap altkatz/homebrew-gcc_cross_compilers`, but it didn't work.

Then I used MacPort like this and it worked:

`$ port search i386-elf-gcc`

`$ sudo port install i386-elf-gcc`

This installed `i386-elf-gcc @4.7.2` successfully for me.

However, I couldn't find `i386-elf-gdb` in MacPort or HomeBrew. So I downloaded the source file of gdb and change the configure(`./configure` file), then  `make` `make install` and it is ok now.

For details:
https://icoderme.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/install-i386-elf-gdb-on-mac-os-x/